# How to pass environment variables to a new ssh-initiated login session?

Tags: ssh, zsh, environment-variables

Suppose that some variable `FOO` is defined (and `export`-ed) in the current environment.  Let me call this environment `E0`.

Now, I log into some other Unix system using `ssh`.

```
% ssh frobozz@for.example.com
```

Let me call the environment of this newly established session `E1`.

*In general*, `FOO` will not be defined in `E1`, and, in the exceptional cases where it is, *in general* its value will be set independently of the value of `FOO` in `E0`.

How can I arrange things so that, upon log in via `ssh`, the variable `FOO` is set in `E1` to the value it has in `E0` (and, ideally, `export`-ed in `E1` as well)?

In case it matters, I'm using `zsh` for both `E0` and `E1`.

For the answer to this question, assume that I do not have any control over the configuration of the `sshd` process running on `for.example.com`.  This rules out, in particular, any solution that requires modifying `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, or the like, on `for.example.com`.

Also, assume that the value of `FOO` is not constant; it will change from one login session to another.  In particular, `FOO` may not be set in `FOO` at all, in which case it is ok if the effect on `E1` is analogous to that of `FOO=` or `export FOO=` or `unset FOO`.

---

**UPDATE:** I tried this

```
% ssh frobozz@for.example.com FOO=$FOO env
```

...and indeed, the output shows that `FOO` is set as specified.  But I have not figured out how to apply this idea when initiating a login session.  Specifically, if I run

```
% ssh frobozz@for.example.com FOO=$FOO
```

...the command just returns without establishing a connection (I figure that `ssh` interprets `FOO=$FOO` as the "command" to run on the remote host).  On the other hand, after I run this

```
% ssh frobozz@for.example.com FOO=$FOO zsh
```

...I never see the shell prompt from the remote host; the command just hangs there.  (I do, however, get a password prompt from `ssh` right before this.)  The same thing happens for other variants of the last command, such as

```
% ssh frobozz@for.example.com FOO=$FOO /path/to/zsh
% ssh frobozz@for.example.com FOO=$FOO env zsh
% ssh frobozz@for.example.com env FOO=$FOO zsh
% ssh frobozz@for.example.com env FOO=$FOO zsh -l
% ssh frobozz@for.example.com 'env FOO=$FOO zsh'
```

**UPDATE2:** Actually, what looked like "hanging" turns out to be that the prompt is not visible.  I can still run commands.  Also, the sequence of zsh initialization files that gets run upon login is different from normal, and (perhaps not suprisingly) the environment is *substantially* (and non-trivially, IOW above and beyond `FOO`) different from normal.

**UPDATE3:** With help from dave_alcarin and meuh I found that this gets pretty close to what I am after:

```
% ssh -t frobozz@for.example.com env FOO=$FOO zsh -l -s
```

There are still some non-trivial differences between the new environment and the normal one that I need to sort out, but this is pretty close to what I want.

Comment: does this correspond to your situation? http://superuser.com/questions/48783/how-can-i-pass-an-environment-variable-through-an-ssh-command

Comment: @dave_alcarin: yes, thank you.  (The accepted answer in that thread does not work for me, but some of the other answers do.)

Comment: I saw that after your last edit, maybe the accepted was not your thing, but some other answers suggested other methods, which can be adapted to your dynamic setting

Comment: @dave_alcarin: I spoke too soon.  See my UPDATE.

Comment: this is wild speculation: try `ssh frobozz@for.example.com 'env FOO=$FOO zsh'`

Comment: @dave_alcarin: same as with the other `env`-based ones (no prompt, etc.).

Comment: use `ssh -t ... FOO=$FOO zsh` to have a pty.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

SSH has a feature to pass environment variables from the client to the server, but OpenSSH disables it in the default server configuration. There's one exception: `TERM`, which has a special place in the protocol; but communicating information via `TERM` is awkward because you have to be sure that the client will decode it.

Nevertheless some servers are configured to let some environment variables through. For example, Debian configures the SSH server to allow all variables whose name begins with `LC_`. Usually these are locale variables, but you can put whatever you like.

If the server isn't configured to allow any variable, you can pass them as part of the command, but there are a couple of wrinkles. The wrinkle you're hitting is that if you pass a command to `ssh`, then by default no terminal is created on the server. So `ssh frobozz@for.example.com FOO=$FOO zsh` does in fact run a shell, but that shell is connected to a pipe, not to a terminal, so it doesn't display a prompt or support command line edition. Nonetheless, you can type commands — try typing `ls` <kbd>Enter</kbd>, and `exit` <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to exit. The solution is to explicitly tell SSH to open a terminal, with the `-t` option.

```
ssh -t frobozz@for.example.com FOO=$FOO zsh
```

Depending on what your login shell is, you may want to run

```
ssh -t frobozz@for.example.com FOO=$FOO exec zsh
```

to avoid having an extra shell process that's the parent of that explicitly-invoked `zsh`.

The second problem you haven't run into yet is quoting. The SSH protocol transmits a string which is executed by the remote shell. Here, you're passing the string consisting of `FOO=`, followed by the value of `FOO`, followed by a space and `exec zsh`. Thus the value of `FOO` is interpreted as a bit of shell source code, not as a string to store in the `FOO` variable. This makes a difference if the value contains characters that have a special meaning in shell syntax. You need to add an extra level of quoting. Assuming your local shell is zsh, you can use the `q` parameter expansion flag:

```
ssh -t frobozz@for.example.com FOO=${(q)FOO} exec zsh
```

Another difference with the straight case is that you're first running a login shell on the remote side, and then replacing it with a non-login shell. Since the chain starts with a login shell (this cannot be avoided), your `.profile` or `.zprofile` does get run; however the interactive instance of zsh is not a login shell, which might make a difference depending on the content of your dot files. The best solution for that is probably to avoid doing fragile things in your dot files. You can run `zsh -l`, but that runs a second login shell, which is prone to making more of a difference (though you can fix that, too, by making sure that your `.profile` or `.zprofile` is idempotent).