# Don't nest tmux in a remote ssh shell

Tags: shell, ssh, tmux, mosh

I've set up the `.zshrc` of my user account on all of the hosts to which I connect to automatically start `tmux` on login as long as it's not already running.

`if [ -z "$TMUX" ]; then
   tmux attach -d || tmux new
fi`

This works well until I ssh (or mosh) into my own account on a remote host from within a tmux session on the local host. Since the `$TMUX` macro isn't passed from the local host to the remote, tmux launches on the remote host and I now have two nested tmux sessions.

Is there a way to avoid this while keeping the auto-launching behaviour? Ideally I'd like the remote shell to know that it's being launched from within a tmux session on the host that is connecting and to not launch a second tmux instance.

I've already tried checking `$TERM` in the remote shell but it is always `xterm-256color` regardless of whether it is running within a tmux session on the local machine.

Comment: Related: [How to pass environment variables to a new ssh-initiated login session](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/236083/how-to-pass-environment-variables-to-a-new-ssh-initiated-login-session)

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to @mark-plotnick 's comment I think I have solution that works for me.

On the remote host, add to /etc/ssh/sshd_config:

`AcceptEnv TMUX`

On the local host, add to ~/.ssh/config:

`Host *
   SendEnv TMUX`

Now the value of the `$TMUX` env variable is sent to the remote host, and `tmux` no longer launches when the value is non-blank.

I don't mind making the server-side change but I wish I didn't have to edit every client `~/.ssh/config` so I'm open to additional suggestions.

Comment: It's a good workaround but not an always-working solution. Same problem occurs if we login locally such as using `su - <username>` which clears whole environment except `$TERM`.